# Problems with Spring MVC 4 REST security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am having real difficulty adding security to my REST API and I am wondering if someone can help here. I have a set of Model, Controller and DAO classes in order to add, edit and delete customers through my API. I am using the latest version of Spring MVC 4. I want to have some basic authentication so that only a select number of users can do that.

I added the following class to start with:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }    

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

As you can notice I disable csrf after some error messages coming back during testing. I also added the following class in order to initialise `SecurityConfig`.

```
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
     public MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

I added of course in my pom.xml (since I am not using web.xml) the relevant dependencies. So I build my project using maven and then copy and paste the .war file in the tomcat7 webapps folder. When the .war file is loaded I get this error message:

```
Cannot initialize context because there is already a root application context present - check whether you have multiple ContextLoader* definitions in your web.xml!
```

I have also the class below to initialise my Application. I haven't got an implementation of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` in order to add my `SecurityConfig`.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TestApplication.class);
    }
}
```

What is going wrong here? I searched the entire web trying to figure out how to simply add basic authentication to my API bearing in mind that all my configuration is java based rather than web.xml one. I haven't found even one article that can solve the problem I am experiencing. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Still having issues with Spring Security. I removed the `MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` and now when I try to access /customers (a list of customers) I get a login form. When I enter the username and password I get the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:249)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.changeSessionId(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:249)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:202)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.applySessionFixation(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.onAuthentication(AbstractSessionFixationProtectionStrategy.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:216)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
```

Comment: Can you post the web.xml?

Comment: I haven't got a web.xml. As I said above I am using java configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is stating that a root ApplicationContext has already been created. If you did this using Java Configuration you likely created a subclass of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`. The changes should be:

```
public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
     public MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        // remove super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Then update your existing subclass of `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`.

```
public class MessageWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    // ... other overrides ...
}
```

You can find a complete example in the [Hello Spring MVC Security Java Config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/hellomvc.html#verify-securityconfig-is-loaded)

Comment: I removed super(SecurityConfig.class) but I think I am missing something here. I haven't got the MessageWebApplicationInitializer class in my project. I am extending SpringBootServletInitializer to initialise my Application. What else do I need to do?

Comment: Spring Boot is yet another case...remove the subclass of AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer all together. That should fix your problem. If not post back what happens.

Comment: OK I removed the subclass with 'AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer' and now the war file can be deployed. I get the login screen and as soon as I enter the username and password I get this exception: 
                                                javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:267)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)

Comment: Look at my edits above in the main question to see where I am right now.